# Problem in downloading any song or movie

Tags: firefox

I am unable to download any file. I am using ubuntu 12.04 and firefox. The files instead of downloading starts playing online.

Comment: You should right click for options to do with the link. no doubt there is a "save as" option.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to Edit --> Preferences.
2. Select Applications tab.
3. As shown in the image, change to **save file** for every content type..
   [image]